How to trim the transparency out of an image but optionally keep a minimum size and position
I have an image that has transparent padding around the edge of it. I also have the content bounds of the image (top, left, width and height) but sometimes it exceeds those bounds.
I'm trying to trim the image of all transparent pixels BUT optionally I want to keep a minimum bounds.
For example, let's say I have 10 images that are all 1000x1000. On some of them the content is positioned at 100x100 and the content size is 100x100. Sometimes the content has a border or other overflowing content and so the content starts before that. On some of the images the bounds would be
{top:100, left:100, width: 100, height: 100}

If there was a 10 pixel border or other overflowing content the bounds might be:
{top:90, left: 90, width: 120, height: 120}

How would I trim the transparent pixels out of the image?
Here is what I have so far:
trimImage(image) {
   var spritePixels = bitmapData;
   var spriteImage = image as HTMLImageElement;
   var data = spritePixels; // Uint8buffer
   var spriteWidth = sprite.width;
   var spriteHeight = sprite.height;
   var firstTopPixel = 0;
   var spritePixelLength = spritePixels.length;
   var newImageData = null;
   var newBounds = {top:0, left:0, width:0, height:0}

   var firstRowFound = false;
   var firstColumnFound = false;
   var firstRowWithContent = 0;
   var lastRowWithContent = 0;
   var firstColumnWithContent = 0;
   var lastColumnWithContent = 0;
   var pixel = -1;
   var row = 0;
   var column = 0;


   for(let i = 0; i < spritePixelLength; i += 4) {
      pixel++;
      const red = spritePixels[i];
      const green = spritePixels[i + 1];
      const blue = spritePixels[i + 2];
      const alpha = spritePixels[i + 3];
      row = Math.floor(pixel / spriteWidth);
      column = pixel - spriteWidth * row;
      //console.log("row: "+ row + " col: " + column);
      
      // ROWS
      // get first top row with a pixel in it
      if (firstRowFound==false && alpha!=0){
         firstRowWithContent = row;
         firstRowFound = true;
         console.log("First non transparent pixel found at row: ");
         console.log("row: "+ row + " col: " + column);
      }
      
      // get last row with a content in it
      if (alpha!=0){
         lastRowWithContent = row;
      }
      
      // COLUMNS
      // get first column with content in it
      if (firstColumnFound==false && alpha!=0) {
         console.log("First non transparent pixel found at column: ");
         console.log("row: "+ row + " col: " + column);
         firstColumnWithContent = column;
         firstColumnFound = true;
      }
      
      // get last column with content in it
      if (alpha!=0){
         lastColumnWithContent = column;
      }
   }

   var bounds = {
      top: firstRowWithContent, 
      bottom: lastRowWithContent, 
      left: firstColumnWithContent,
      right: lastColumnWithContent,
      x: firstColumnWithContent,
      y: firstRowWithContent,
      width: lastColumnWithContent - firstColumnWithContent + 1,
      height: lastRowWithContent - firstRowWithContent + 1
   }

   // bounds bottom and right might need + 1? 
   console.log(bounds);
   // todo: get image at bounds
  
   return bounds;
}

var results = trimImage(image);


should the function automatically detect the transparent parts? and keep only the minimal rectangle of visible content?

@ITgoldman yes. that's correct. I think I figured it out. I'm testing now

See also "Cropping an HTML canvas to the width/height of its visible pixels (content)?"

Example image
Using the following image of 320x320 pixels with transparent padding:

Source: myself (feel free to use for any purpose)
Example code
In this example, you'll see the difference between before and after, each image with a red border around it to show where the transparent image padding ends.
The function trimImage iterates over every row and column of pixels to detect the outer boundaries of the painted pixels. It then redraws the pixels within that boundary onto a resized canvas.


<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0"
    />

    <title>Strip transparent padding</title>

    <style>
      img, canvas {
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: 0 10px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module">
      async function trimImage(image) {
        // Create a canvas
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        document.body.appendChild(canvas)

        // Convert the image to a bitmap
        const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(image)
        const { width, height } = bitmap

        // Get pixels
        canvas.width = width
        canvas.height = height
        context.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0)
        const { data: pixels } = context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height)
        context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height)

        // Find new bounds by ignoring transparent pixels
        const bounds = { top: height, left: width, right: 0, bottom: 0 }

        for (const row of Array(height).keys()) {
          for (const col of Array(width).keys()) {
            if (pixels[row * width * 4 + col * 4 + 3] !== 0) {
              if (row < bounds.top) bounds.top = row
              if (col < bounds.left) bounds.left = col
              if (col > bounds.right) bounds.right = col
              if (row > bounds.bottom) bounds.bottom = row
            }
          }
        }

        const newWidth = bounds.right - bounds.left
        const newHeight = bounds.bottom - bounds.top

        // Draw new image
        canvas.width = newWidth
        canvas.height = newHeight
        context.drawImage(
          bitmap,
          bounds.left,
          bounds.top,
          newWidth,
          newHeight,
          0,
          0,
          newWidth,
          newHeight,
        )
      }

      // Load the image
      const image = new Image()
      // image.src = './images/vector-die-with-transparency.webp'
      image.src = 'data:image/webp;base64,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'
      image.onload = async () => {
        document.body.append('Original:')
        document.body.append(image)
        document.body.append(document.createElement('br'))

        document.body.append('Trimmed:')
        await trimImage(image)
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



Note: I had to paste in the image as base64 in this snippet specifically because I couldn't load an image from cross origin (stack overflow cdn) because getImageData() will error as The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data.
Under normal circumstances you should be able to use the uploaded blob or imported image that's hosted on the same origin. If not, be sure to check out  cross-origin method.
